BlueZ PushMessage Problems
I am trying to use the PushMessage function of BlueZ to transfer a text message to the outbox of an iPhone for sending.
The pushmessage function returns the file transfer path correctly, which immediately returns an error. The only update from the transfer is "queued" and then "error", which leads me to believe the iPhone simply rejects the transfer for some reason. However, this is supposed to be a supported feature according to the MAP protocol.
I am testing/running the function via D-Feet to simplify testing. Running the same function via my own code (C++) produces the same results.
Has anyone successfully pushed an sms message file to the outbox of a phone using BlueZ/MAP connection and the PushMessage function in the MessageAccess1 interface?
Function:
PushMessage (String file, String folder, Dict of {String, Variant} args)

Other info:

Ubuntu machine
No other issues with Bluetooth connectivity, including pulling messages, listing messages etc.
The device is paired, trusted, not blocked etc.
iPhone has sync contacts and show notifications checked off.

Sample Message:
BEGIN:BMSG
VERSION:1.0
STATUS:READ
TYPE:SMS_GSM
FOLDER:
BEGIN:BENV
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=UTF-8:test
TEL;CHARSET=UTF-8:+12345678
END:VCARD
BEGIN:BBODY
CHARSET:UTF-8
LANGUAGE:ENGLISH
LENGTH:44
BEGIN:MSG
test
END:MSG
END:BBODY
END:BENV
END:BMSG

Steps:

MAP session established.
Folder set to /telecom/msg/outbox.
PushMessage called with path to file containing message, other arguments blank.
Transfer status updates to queued.
Transfer status updates to error.

Tried:

Message format makes no difference
Calling function with different arguments makes no difference
Trying to push a message to any other folder (inbox) produces the same result

BTMON Output
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 343
                                                                     #2 [hci0] 7.587024
      Channel: 9495 len 339 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        2c 16 02 01 4f cb 62 40 69 e0 97 01 01 00 03 42  ,...O.b@i......B
        00 10 78 2d 62 74 2f 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 00 c3  ..x-bt/message..
        00 00 01 24 4c 00 06 14 01 01 48 01 27 42 45 47  ...$L.....H.'BEG
        49 4e 3a 42 4d 53 47 0d 0a 56 45 52 53 49 4f 4e  IN:BMSG..VERSION
        3a 31 2e 30 0d 0a 53 54 41 54 55 53 3a 52 45 41  :1.0..STATUS:REA
        44 0d 0a 54 59 50 45 3a 53 4d 53 5f 47 53 4d 0d  D..TYPE:SMS_GSM.
        0a 46 4f 4c 44 45 52 3a 0d 0a 42 45 47 49 4e 3a  .FOLDER:..BEGIN:
        42 45 4e 56 0d 0a 42 45 47 49 4e 3a 56 43 41 52  BENV..BEGIN:VCAR
        44 0d 0a 56 45 52 53 49 4f 4e 3a 32 2e 31 0d 0a  D..VERSION:2.1..
        4e 3b 43 48 41 52 53 45 54 3d 55 54 46 2d 38 3a  N;CHARSET=UTF-8:
        0d 0a 54 45 4c 3b 43 48 41 52 53 45 54 3d 55 54  ..TEL;CHARSET=UT
        46 2d 38 3a 2b 31 38 34 38 32 34 34 33 30 30 38  F-8:+18482443008
        0d 0a 45 4e 44 3a 56 43 41 52 44 0d 0a 42 45 47  ..END:VCARD..BEG
        49 4e 3a 42 42 4f 44 59 0d 0a 43 48 41 52 53 45  IN:BBODY..CHARSE
        54 3a 55 54 46 2d 38 0d 0a 4c 41 4e 47 55 41 47  T:UTF-8..LANGUAG
        45 3a 45 4e 47 4c 49 53 48 0d 0a 4c 45 4e 47 54  E:ENGLISH..LENGT
        48 3a 34 34 0d 0a 42 45 47 49 4e 3a 4d 53 47 0d  H:44..BEGIN:MSG.
        0a 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 66 6c 69 70 2e 69 74  .https://flip.it
        2f 4f 67 6e 44 66 64 0d 0a 45 4e 44 3a 4d 53 47  /OgnDfd..END:MSG
        0d 0a 45 4e 44 3a 42 42 4f 44 59 0d 0a 45 4e 44  ..END:BBODY..END
        3a 42 45 4e 56 0d 0a 45 4e 44 3a 42 4d 53 47 0d  :BENV..END:BMSG.
        0a 1c e6                                         ...             
< HCI Command: Exit Sniff Mode (0x02|0x0004) plen 2                                                             #3 [hci0] 7.587142
        Handle: 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                       #4 [hci0] 7.588463
      Exit Sniff Mode (0x02|0x0004) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6                                                                          #5 [hci0] 7.814580
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        Mode: Active (0x00)
        Interval: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3                                                                     #6 [hci0] 7.820539
        Handle: 1
        Max slots: 5
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3                                                                     #7 [hci0] 7.821439
        Handle: 1
        Max slots: 5
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                          #8 [hci0] 7.826457
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 1
        Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 13                                                                      #9 [hci0] 7.838646
      Channel: 70 len 9 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        2c 17 90 00 05 97 01 a5 f6                       ,........       
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 14                                                                     #10 [hci0] 7.838772
      Channel: 9495 len 10 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        2e 17 82 00 06 49 00 03 65 2e                    .....I..e.      
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                         #11 [hci0] 7.863561
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 1
        Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                     #12 [hci0] 7.869710
      Channel: 70 len 7 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        2e 18 d0 00 03 ae aa                             .......         
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 8                                                                      #13 [hci0] 7.989773
      Channel: 70 len 4 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        01 18 15 56                                      ...V            
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 8                                                                      #14 [hci0] 8.074191
      Channel: 9495 len 4 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        01 18 14 61                                      ...a            
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                         #15 [hci0] 8.099517
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 1
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6                                                                        #16 [hci0] 13.212618
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        Mode: Sniff (0x02)
        Interval: 240.000 msec (0x0180)
> HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6                                                                        #17 [hci0] 21.135741
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        Mode: Active (0x00)
        Interval: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3                                                                   #18 [hci0] 21.140605
        Handle: 1
        Max slots: 5


This doesn't seem to be enough information for it to be a Minimal, Reproducible Example. For example, what programming language is this in? What argument values are you using? Have you got any of the commands to work e.g. ListFolders? For debug information, have you tried having sudo btmon running in a separate terminal to see if BlueZ is giving an error? Editing your question with this information would be helpful for other to help.

I am using C++ and QT for the code, but the behavior is the same when using something like D-Feet and calling the function directly. I have mentioned that there are no other issues listing messages, pulling messages etc. This is the only thing not working correctly. I think the question is simply: has anyone used pushmessage to send an sms to a phone via bluez successfully and if yes, how?

The format for outgoing messages is different from the format of incoming messages. Here's the format that worked for me:
BEGIN:BMSG
VERSION:1.0
STATUS:READ
TYPE:SMS_GSM
FOLDER: Where on the phone it's supposed to go (outbox/inbox etc)
BEGIN:BENV
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:
TEL:Phone number to send to goes here
END:VCARD
BEGIN:BBODY
CHARSET:UTF-8
LANGUAGE:UNKNOWN
LENGTH:Length of message
BEGIN:MSG
Text message goes here
END:MSG
END:BBODY
END:BENV
END:BMSG

The specific issue was with the following line in the original message I was sending, which I had copied, format wise, from incoming messages:
TEL;CHARSET=UTF-8:

Any of the lines containing ;CHARSET=UTF-8 would result in the message transfer being an error. Replace with TEL: only or whatever the actual line is supposed to indicate, without the charset variable.

Another thing to check for is that when creating the message, "\r\n" is added at the end of every line, per BMESSAGE standard. I was only adding "\n" which was causing the message to not be parsed properly.
